# Java exceptions rationale

Tags: java, exception, theory

A quite theoretical question this time. So I'm using this function in Eclipse:

```
CsvReader csv = new CsvReader("src/maindroite.csv");
```

Which can't run because "Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException". Ok, I understand that I have to add something for the case where the file doesn't exist, at which point I usually add a few lines to catche the exception and throw it away. But my question is: why do I need to catch the exception **even when the file do exist**? And actually, why do I even have this Exception thing for some functions and not others?

For example, let's say I'm trying to run:

```
ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("src/square.jpg");
ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon("src/circle.jpg");
```

Where "square.jpg" exists but not "circle.jpg". The program will create icon1, but not icon2, because it can't. But I don't need to add an ExceptionHandler for the case where the image doesn't exist. What is the difference between both functions?

To sum it up:

- Why do I have to add an ExceptionHandler when the file **do** exist?
- Why do I have to add an ExceptionHandler for some functions and not others?

Thanks!

Comment: Because the JVM can't read your mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Why do I have to add an ExceptionHandler when the file do exist?*

**Basically you have to add it regardless, because you cannot write conditional code like that, in short there is no way that for the compiler to know before runtime if the file exists or not, therefore the compiler forces yo to put a try/catch block, since FileNotFoundException is a [checked](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/exceptions.doc.html) exception.**

*Why do I have to add an ExceptionHandler for some functions and not others?*

***You only have to add try/catch blocks to anything that throws a checked exception, that is anything that does *****NOT* inherit from `RuntimeException` or `Error` classes. Subclasses of `Error` and `RuntimeException` are not checked exceptions and you may either put the try/catch or not the compiler does not care. Since the constructor for `ImageIcon` does not throw any kind of exceptions and will simply return null if the image does not exist there is no need to do a try/catch block.***

Comment: Any subclass of RuntimeException (including RuntimeException itself) is also unchecked.

Comment: @yshavit Updated my answer, to make it more accurate.

Comment: So, when ImageIcon returns null because the file doesn't exist, is it an integrated exception handling?

Comment: @Mikalichov I am not sure how that is implemented internally for that constructor in particular, but most likely it catches the exception and then "handles" it by returning null.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it better anyway, thanks!
edit: actually, is there a way to know beforehand if the function throws a checked/unchecked exception? Or is the only way to "try and hope"?

Comment: @Mikalichov You're welcome. Your IDE (I recommend Eclipse) should tell you when it is needed, and if not the compiler will tell you. Otherwise you can look at the method signature and if it is throwing a checked exception it MUST (it is enforced by compiler) declare the exception i.e. myMethod() throws Exception.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the file exists now, on your system, it might not exist later.  Or you may give this code to someone who doesn't have `src/square.jpg`.  Or maybe there will be a hardware malfunction where something on your hard drive gets corrupted and accidentally deletes src/square.jpg.  Maybe the user might even just delete the files.

Exception handling in Java forces you to think about what would happen in the worst case if something really bad happens (like `src/square.jpg` goes missing).  Do you crash? Is it okay to continue on like nothing happened?  You get to decide how to handle these failure modes in the catch clause.

Some functions don't require you to handle exceptions because there isn't really anything that could go wrong in the functions that you could be reasonably expected to handle.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Why do I have to add an ExceptionHandler when the file do[es] exist?

Because the Java compiler cannot know whether or not that file will actually exist at some arbitrary runtime.  (Suppose the file was deleted after you compiled but before you ran the program?)  Basically, your code must always have the logic required to handle conditions which aren't expected to happen but might anyway.

> 2) Why do I have to add an ExceptionHandler for some functions and not others?

There could be various reasons but here's the one you're probably seeing.  Exceptions are thrown per method but caught per try/catch block or per method if they are propagated upwards.  In your example, you could wrap each call to the `ImageIcon` constructor in its own try/catch block or both together, depending on what you want to do:

```
try {
  icon1 = new ImageIcon("f1.jpg");
} catch (Exception e) { /* Handle the case for missing "f1.jpg". */ }
try {
  icon2 = new ImageIcon("f2.jpg");
} catch (Exception e) { /* Handle the case for missing "f2.jpg". */ }
```

Compared to:

```
try {
  icon1 = new ImageIcon("f1.jpg");
  icon2 = new ImageIcon("f2.jpg");
} catch (Exception e) { /* Handle the case for missing "f1" or "f2". */ }
```

Comment: Ok, so I can add an exception handler to ImageIcon; does this mean ImageIcon returns null when not finding the file, AND returns that there was an Exception? If so, why isn't it mandatory in this case to handle the possible exception beforehand? Anyway, thanks a lot for this answer, I understand it better.

Comment: @Mikalichov: if a method throws an exception then the flow of control jumps to the exception handler (e.g. catch block); so in this case the function does not return at all so no assignment occurs to the left-hand value (e.g. "icon1") retains the value it had before attempting the call to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Because Java differentiates between what are known as "checked" and "unchecked" exceptions.  It's the source of a lot of heated controversy, as to whether or not unchecked exceptions should even exist, and whether or not API methods should throw exceptions.

**According to the Java Trails:**

> Here's the bottom line guideline: If a client can reasonably be
>   expected to recover from an exception, make it a checked exception. If
>   a client cannot do anything to recover from the exception, make it an
>   unchecked exception.

That's the so-called rationale.

Read more about "the controversy" [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html).

Comment: Ok, at least I'm not the only one wondering. But having to manage exceptions for each function would be quite a pain... But that's another debate, thanks for the insight

Answer (score 0):

Why do I have to add an ExceptionHandler when the file do exist?

It exists for now, but there is no guarantee it will there every time. Could happen because of whole lot of reasons. If there is no file, it doesn't make sense to do InputStream and associated business logic and it is sure that your business won't be successful.

Why do I have to add an ExceptionHandler for some functions and not others?

Some Classes like Imageicon, they are not show stoppers for your business processing. If they are not there, that's Ok, you can still continue with your core business logic.

I feel this is main reason why some class mandate exceptions and some are not.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind checked exceptions is that they make it possible for the caller of a function to know what exceptions might escape from it.  You don't have to actually catch the `FileNotFoundException` if you don't want to, provided you add `throws FileNotFoundException` to your method signature to let your caller know that such an exception might escape from your method.

The concept is a good one, but unfortunately there's no concise way to state that you want to catch all exceptions that aren't overly severe and wrap them into a common exception type for your caller.  In a lot of cases, when an exception occurs, the real message you want to convey is either "the method didn't complete, but the system doesn't seem to be on fire and any side-effects have been undone", or "the method didn't complete, and the system doesn't seem to be on fire, but there may have been other side-effects."  It would be helpful if there were a concise syntax to indicate regions of code where exceptions should be caught and wrapped to one of the above formats, but alas there is not.